# Are processed food considered Haram?

Tags: halal-haram, food

Do processed food such as chips, cold-drink and other processed foot constitute Haram food? What's the ruling on processed food?

Comment: Why would processed food be haraam? Everything is permissible unless specifically said otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

Good Question. Now I am no scholar, but my understanding tells me;

If the food contains Haraam or najis elements, then yes it will be Haram.

By Haraam elements I mean, the whole process from preparing to cooking to serving to eating.

But if there are no Najis, haram elements in the food... then logic tells us that it has to be Halaal.

This is the basic criteria to know.

Thanks, And remember Keep asking ! For Allah says in the Qur'an, "Are not those who ponder (think, contemplate, ask, question) better"

Comment: Yes, A lot of processed food has najas take chicken nuggets for example or sausage, but not all suppliers use the same technique!!

Answer (score 0):

Many Islamic countries cannot get unprocessed food. If it contains traces of foods that are Haram, such as pork or alcohol, you cannot eat/drink it. That is the general rule. Chips fried in vegetable oil would be fine, pig fat, big no-no.

Answer (score -1):

The rule is : the food to be halal , the  original material must be  not consist of Haram food  or mixed by some Haram